# Personalize NavBar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to personalize the navBar (router-flux library). In particular I'm checking the role of an user when the app starts, in this way in the homepage if the user has the role: "Role_Plus" he cannot logout, so the text "logout" desappear, in the other cases the text is displayed.

I have create in the componentDidMount a code to check the users's credentials  and it works. But in the render() part of the code there is an error so I can't use.

I have tried to use also a flag that is set to 1 when the user is Role_Plus, but this method doesn't work to.

> (I commented the code in the parts where there is the error.)

This is the code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: ''
    };
    this.flag = '';
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkUser()
    }

  checkUser(){
    User.getLoggedUser()
        .then(dataUserLogged => {   
          if (dataUserLogged !== null) {
            global.user = new User(JSON.parse(dataUserLogged));
            // The console log print the right role without problems
            console.log("User's Role: " + global.user.data.Roles)
            if(global.user.data.Roles == "ROLE_PLUS") {
              this.setState ({ flag: 1})
            }
          } })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      }


  render() {
    console.log("FLAG: " + this.state.flag)    
    return (     
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene
            key="homepage"
            component={Homepage}
            type="reset"    

            // I have tried this method but it doesn't work (The logout text is always display)
            /*rightTitle={ this.state.flag === 1 ? "" : "Logout"}
            onRight={
              this.state.flag === 1 
              ? () => {}
              : () => Actions.refresh(App.logout())
            }*/

            // In this case there is an error: "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined "
            rightTitle={ global.user.data.Roles !== "ROLE_PLUS" ? "Logout" : ""}
            onRight={
              globaluser.data.Roles !== "ROLE_PLUS"
                ? () => Actions.refresh(App.logout())
                : () => {}
            }
          />
```

In your opinion how can I do to check the credentials user and display the text `"logout"` if the role is not: `"Role_Plus"` ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`'Global.user'` is a `local variable` in a function and the value of `'Global.user'` is unknown elsewhere. Please pass the value to the `status` value.

```js
 componentWillMount() {
    this.checkUser()
    }

checkUser(){
    User.getLoggedUser()
        .then(dataUserLogged => {   
          if (dataUserLogged !== null) {
            global.user = new User(JSON.parse(dataUserLogged));
            // The console log print the right role without problems
            console.log("User's Role: " + global.user.data.Roles)
            if(global.user.data.Roles == "ROLE_PLUS") {
              this.setState ({ flag: global.user.data.Roles})
              console.log("this is come in?");
            }
          } })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      }
...
rightTitle={ this.state.flag === "ROLE_PLUS" ? "Logout" : ""}
```

Comment: So: this.state.flag === "ROLE_PLUS" ? "Logout" : ""

In this way if the flag is equal to role plus don't show Logout?

Comment: If the value of 'flag' is "ROLE_PLUS", return 'logout'.

Comment: @Jack23  Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Oh I should do that if the value is Role_plus the text logout disappear

Comment: Please check the current flag value in the log.

Comment: The value is right, is Role_Plus, and if use the condtion that you wirte the text disappear, but for all the users.

It should be: this.state.flag !== "ROLE_PLUS" ? "Logout" : "" but also in this case it is displayed

Comment: Are you saying you'll mark it when it's just a condition?

Comment: I'm saying that if the user has the role: "Role_Plus" the text Logout must not be displayed, for all other users yes

Comment: It is shown when the conditions are satisfied. If conditions are not applicable, check the type of condition.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve in this way:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: 'ROLE_PLUS'
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkUser()
    }

  checkUser(){
    User.getLoggedUser()
        .then(dataUserLogged => {   
          if (dataUserLogged !== null) {
            global.user = new User(JSON.parse(dataUserLogged));
            console.log("User's Role: " + global.user.data.Roles)
            if(global.user.data.Roles != "ROLE_PLUS") {
              this.setState ({ flag: ''})
            }
          } })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      }


  render() {
    console.log("FLAG: " + this.state.flag)    
    return (     
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene
            key="homepage"
            component={Homepage}
            type="reset"    
            rightTitle={ this.state.flag != 'ROLE_PLUS' ? "Logout" : ""}
            onRight={
              this.state.flag != 'ROLE_PLUS'
              ? () => Actions.refresh(App.logout())
              : () => {}
            }
          />
```